# Beautify js code in atom editor on save according to eslint configuration

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, eslint

I am using [Atom](https://atom.io/) as my code editor of choice and am finding it hard to implement functionality to beautify code. I am relying quite heavily on [eslint](http://eslint.org/) package and just got [beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) to clean up my code on save. issue is that once code is beautified it results in some minor eslint errors and I am looking for a way to either set up beautify plugin in a way that respects eslint rules or use something else that does the job.

Comment: Can you be more specific about which eslint errors you're getting on save?

Comment: so which package are you use for that ?

Answer (score 7):

You may want to use an Atom plugin called [Prettier Eslint](https://atom.io/packages/prettier-eslint) that formats code according to `eslint` config file (`.eslintrc`). It uses eslint's `--fix` flag to fix issues.

Edit: Looks like its [Prettier-atom](https://atom.io/packages/prettier-atom) now. Thanks, @dube.

Comment: Prettier Eslint is deprecated, but it's integrated in Prettier-Atom

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like your `beautify` settings aren't matched up with your `eslint` rules. For example, the `eslint` `indent` rule might be set to `4` while `beautify` `indent` is set to `2`.

The `beautify` plugin has some settings to customize how it beautifies your code. You can read about those settings [in the docs](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify#configuration). Unfortunately there's only 17 settings so it might not be possible to sync the 2 packages.

If you find you need more control over the auto-formatting in Atom you might want to check out the [ESFormatter](https://atom.io/packages/esformatter) package. It has more than 250 options, which might suit your needs better if you have some non-standard ESLint rules.